# What is the problem with my code for finding whether a number is prime or not

Tags: python, math, numbers, primes

```
N = int(input())
flag = False
if N <= 2:
  print('no')
for j in range(2, int(N**0.5)+1):
  if N%j == 0:
    flag = True
if flag == False:
  print('yes')
else:
  print('no')
```

The logic is same everywhere I saw the solution, but somehow codechef shows that it is a wrong answer, as I don't have a pro subscription of codechef, I cannot see the failed cases.

Comment: There's no need for `else: pass`. Just leave out the `else:` block entirely.

Comment: `for j in range(2, N):` => `for j in range(2, int(N**0.5)+1):` to break the complexity, then break if your flag is true

Comment: I did that and then too it shows an error. Memory used is 9.6M and time is 0.04s

Comment: even better, it could break when the flag is made True (since it's found a prime divisor) to not have to iterate through unnecessary checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
N = int(input())
flag = False
for j in range(2, N):
    if N % j == 0:
        flag = True
if not flag and N > 1:  # Important: 0 and 1 are not prime numbers
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: I would like to know what was the mistake with my piece of code, where did I go wrong

Comment: 0 and 1 are not prime numbers, which is a special case inside the logic

Answer (score 2):

This code is along the right lines (although could be done far more efficiently) for any number above 2, but look at the edge cases - this script gives the result that both 1 and 0 are prime numbers.

Comment: 0 is not in problem domain, but 1 is worth checking.

Comment: I added an if statement above the for `for` loop, to rule out the edge cases, then too it shows wrong answer

Comment: @Xyls047 could you please add the wording of the problem you're solving, or a link to the problem on CodeChef? This may also be an issue with the answer CodeChef is expecting to see.

Comment: @alexhroom This is the link for the CodeChef problem : https://www.codechef.com/problems/PRB01?tab=statement

Comment: @Xyls047 You consider both 1 and 2 not prime?